# How to ensure a date is valid?

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, datetime

My code below assigns certain parts of a file name to a variable. What is important here is the variable "yearandmonth" which is a string formatted as "yyyy-mm"

```
Dim fileparts() As String
            Dim delimiter As String = " - "
            Dim company As String
            Dim type As String
            Dim bank As String
            Dim bankaccount As String
            Dim yearandmonth As String 
            Dim fileyear As String
            Dim filemonth As String

            fileparts = Split(localFileName, delimiter)
            company = fileparts(0)
            type = fileparts(1)
            bank = fileparts(2)
            bankaccount = fileparts(3)
            yearandmonth = Left(fileparts(4), 7) ' RESULTS IN A STRING THAT WILL LOOK LIKE "yyyy-mm"
            fileyear = Left(yearandmonth, 4) ' results in "yyyy"
            filemonth = Right(yearandmonth, 2) ' results in "mm"
```

How can I ensure that the output from "yearandmonth" is a valid year, month and that it contains the "-"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DateTime.TryParse Method to validate if the date string is a valid date format as the code below :

```
Dim dateStrings() As String = {"yyyy-mm"}
Dim dateValue As Date

If DateTime.TryParseExact(mystring, dateStrings, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue) Then
    'Do for Valid Date
Else
    'Do for Invalid Date
End If
```

Comment: This check if it is in the correct format, right? I want to check if the year and month are valid themselves. Ex: 2017/13. "13" would be MM but there are only 12 months. I would like to check this

Comment: The checking should validate whether the year and month pass in is valid. If you want to do a manual check on that particular month value itself, i suppose you should create a simple validation method. 

If month < 1 and month  > 12 Then
'Do for valid month
Else 'Do for invalid month
End If

This is just a rough idea on how to do it, you should convert it to vb.net syntax.